# A few very simple statements but why it yields UnboundLocalError

Tags: python

I really cannot see what is wrong with these statements. I checked they are many same error posts here but I cannot find a clear answer. Can anyone explain a bit on this issue? Thanks.

```
myVariable = 10

def printV():
    myVariable = myVariable + 10
    print("inside", myVariable)

printV()

print("outside", myVariable)
```

Comment: This question has been asked many times (I'm just trying to find the right duplicate). Short answer- put `global myVariable` at the start of the function.

Comment: Do you *want* to use global variables tho? Alternatively you could pass `myVariable` into `printV()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the method doesn't know what `myVariable` is because it isn't scoped well in local. I suggest you do this.

```
myVariable = 10

def printV():
    global myVariable
    myVariable = myVariable + 10
    print("inside", myVariable)

printV()

print("outside", myVariable)
```

Comment: `global myVariable` at the top has no effect.  The global/local/nonlocal scope distinction only exists in functions, not at module level.